# curses library import error pypy

Tags: python, pypy

I have been using pypy 1.4 which is said to be fully compatible with cpython 2.5 but when I try to import the curses module, I get an import error evn though the curses module is available.Any pointers why this may be happening?

Comment: Please provide a link for “…is said to be fully compatible with cpython 2.5”.

Answer (score 3):

The `curses` Python module uses the `_curses` C module.
The [PyPy Python compatibility page](http://pypy.org/compat.html) says the following (with points emphasized by me):

> PyPy implements the Python language version 2.5. It supports all of the core language, passing Python test suite (with minor modifications that were already accepted in the main python in newer versions). It supports **most** of the commonly used Python standard library modules; details below.
>
> PyPy has alpha-level support for the CPython C API, however, as of 1.4.1 release this feature is not yet complete. Most libraries will require a bit of effort to work, but there are known success stories. Check out PyPy blog for updates.
>
> C extensions **need** to be recompiled for PyPy in order to work. Depending on your build system, it might work out of the box or will be slightly harder. In order to instruct pypy to **load a CPython extension** (compiled with supplied Python.h), run following line:

```
import cpyext
```

Further down that page, there is a list of standard library modules supported by PyPy. I don't see `curses` there, although there is a `_minimal_curses` which *might* be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the bug report](https://bugs.pypy.org/issue879).